# Gutenberg update attributes in a custom component

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a custom post type for products. I am trying to create a block in Gutenberg that allows the user to select a product and then show the product information in tile format.

I have been able to create a dropdown with product name and Ids, I am having trouble in saving the selected product id to attributes.

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { withSelect } from "@wordpress/data";
import { SelectControl } from "@wordpress/components";

function edit({ products, setAttributes, attributes } = props) {
    let options = [];
    if (products) {
        products.map((product) => {
            options.push({
                value: product.id,
                label: product.title.rendered,
            });
        });
    }
    return (
        <div className="product-selector">
            <SelectControl
                label={__("Select Product:")}
                value={attributes.selectedProductId}
                onChange={(product) => {
                    setAttributes({ selectedProductId: product });
                }}
                options={options}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default withSelect((select, props) => {
    return {
        products: select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "products"),
    };
})(edit);
```

Comment: What type is attribute `selectedProductId` defined as in registerBlockType() and does it match what you are trying to save?

Comment: Thanks, @S.Walsh attribute type is number, and product Id is a string. I have used parseInt to change product id to the number and this worked.